# How to schedule Teams Meeting from SharePoint calendar

Tags: 2013, calendar, microsoft-teams

We use SharePoint 2013 and Skype for Business. Now we also just adopted MS Teams.

When I connect a SharePoint calendar to Outlook and schedule a meeting there I can make it a "Skype Meeting". In this case the link for the Skype Meeting is the one for me as a user (e.g. https://meet.company.com/johnsmith/ABCDEFG).

However when trying to schedule it as a Teams meeting I get the following error:

[image]

Is there a way to schedule Teams meetings from within a on-premise SharePoint 2013 calendar (in Outlook) or does this calendar act as a completely different user for which I do not have these permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Teams are looking for a specific set of permissions on the owner’s mailbox when generating the Teams meeting in Outlook. In order to create a meeting as a delegate, the delegate must be a true **‘delegate’** under the owner’s mailbox **AND** have either *‘Author‘* or *‘Editor‘* access to the calendar:

[image]

See reference: https://blog.markdepalma.com/?p=657

Comment: There is no mailbox or owner involved. I get this message when trying to create a Teams meeting in a SharePoint Calendar that is connected to Outlook.